# Slick projection with multiple MappedColumnType

Tags: scala, slick, slick-3.0

I have the following simplified code to reflect the issue I'm facing.  It's using slick 3.1.1, with scala 2.10.4 and mysql.

I have a User table, with one column that has Option[Seq[String]] and the other column is Seq[String].

There are 2 MappedColumnType; that will convert the Seq[String] to String, and Option[Seq[String]] to String

Below is the simplified code:

```
package models

import slick.driver.MySQLDriver.api._

case class User(id: Long,
                name: Option[String],
                cities: Option[Seq[String]] = None,
                countries: Seq[String])

class UserMapping(tag: Tag) extends Table[User](tag, "USERS") {

  implicit val stringListMapper = MappedColumnType.base[Seq[String], String](
    list => list.mkString(","),
    string => string.split(',').toSeq
  )

  implicit val stringOptionalListMapper = MappedColumnType.base[Option[Seq[String]], String](
    list => list.get.mkString(","),
    string => Some(string.split(',').toSeq)
  )

  def id: Rep[Long] = column[Long]("ID", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)
  def name: Rep[Option[String]] = column[Option[String]]("NAME")
  def cities: Rep[Option[Seq[String]]] = column[Option[Seq[String]]]("CITIES")(stringOptionalListMapper)
  def countries: Rep[Seq[String]] = column[Seq[String]]("COUNTRIES")(stringListMapper)

  // scalastyle:off method.name public.methods.have.type
  def * = (id, name, cities, countries) <> (User.tupled, User.unapply)
  // scalastyle:on method.name public.methods.have.type

}
```

The compiler is failing at the projection:

```
[error] Slick does not know how to map the given types.
[error] Possible causes: T in Table[T] does not match your *     projection. Or you use an unsupported type in a Query (e.g. scala List).
[error]   Required level: slick.lifted.FlatShapeLevel
[error]      Source type: (slick.lifted.Rep[Long], slick.lifted.Rep[Option[String]], slick.lifted.Rep[Option[Seq[String]]], slick.lifted.Rep[Seq[String]])
[error]    Unpacked type: (Long, Option[String], Option[Seq[String]], Seq[String])
[error]      Packed type: Any
[error]   def * = (id, name, cities, countries) <> (User.tupled, User.unapply)
[error]                                         ^
[error] one error found
[error] (compile:compileIncremental) Compilation failed
[error] Total time: 2 s, completed Jan 23, 2018 3:24:23 PM
```

It works fine if I have only one MappedColumnType defined in here; unfortunately, my data model needs one to be optional and the other to be required. 
Any ideas of what's happening in here? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like that the really important thing is not that there are two mapped column but the fact that they are of the same shape except for `Option`.  This is bad because it makes you introduce two `implicit val`s for mappings and this makes them ambiguous for conversion of `(id, name, cities, countries)` into a `ProvenShape`

If the logic for such shape is actually the same as in your example, then Slick seems to be able to add `Option` wrapper on its own so you are OK with just one (non-`Option`) implicit such as:

```
class UserMapping(tag: Tag) extends Table[User](tag, "USERS") {

  implicit val stringListMapper = MappedColumnType.base[Seq[String], String](
    list => list.mkString(","),
    string => string.split(',').toSeq
  )

  def id: Rep[Long] = column[Long]("ID", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)

  def name: Rep[Option[String]] = column[Option[String]]("NAME")

  def cities: Rep[Option[Seq[String]]] = column[Option[Seq[String]]]("CITIES")   // share stringListMapper

  def countries: Rep[Seq[String]] = column[Seq[String]]("COUNTRIES")        // share stringListMapper

  // scalastyle:off method.name public.methods.have.type
  def * = (id, name, cities, countries) <> (User.tupled, User.unapply)
  // scalastyle:on method.name public.methods.have.type

}
```

However if you are unlucky and mappings for the same shape are actually different so you need to pass them both explicitly to `column` (for example if the separator chars are different), then you will have to explicitly provide an `implicit` evidence of the proper `Shape` such as:

```
class UserMapping(tag: Tag) extends Table[User](tag, "USERS") {

  val stringListMapper = MappedColumnType.base[Seq[String], String](
    list => list.mkString(","),
    string => string.split(',').toSeq
  )

  val stringOptionalListMapper = MappedColumnType.base[Option[Seq[String]], String](
    list => list.get.mkString(","),
    string => Some(string.split(',').toSeq)
  )

  def id: Rep[Long] = column[Long]("ID", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)

  def name: Rep[Option[String]] = column[Option[String]]("NAME")

  def cities: Rep[Option[Seq[String]]] = column[Option[Seq[String]]]("CITIES")(stringOptionalListMapper)

  def countries: Rep[Seq[String]] = column[Seq[String]]("COUNTRIES")(stringListMapper)


  // explicitly provide proper Shape evidence
  import slick.lifted.Shape
  implicit val shape = Shape.tuple4Shape(
    Shape.repColumnShape(longColumnType),
    Shape.optionShape(Shape.repColumnShape(stringColumnType)),
    Shape.repColumnShape(stringOptionalListMapper),
    Shape.repColumnShape(stringListMapper))

  // scalastyle:off method.name public.methods.have.type
  def * = (id, name, cities, countries) <> (User.tupled, User.unapply)
  // scalastyle:on method.name public.methods.have.type

}
```